# Android: 0 supported devices for my app

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've recently uploaded my app to the Google Play Store. After digging through several similar threads on here I still can't solve the issue. When I upload my signed apk, it says that there are no supported devices. According to google it is based off of my app manifest, which can be found below. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sd.sdhydro">
    //permissions
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true" />
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/let"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Home Hydroponics System"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="About" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="Settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NewUserActivity"
            android:label="New User" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UserHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ManageEquipmentIDsActivity"
            android:label="Equipment ID Management" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EquipmentHistoryActivity"
            android:label="Equipment History" />
        <activity
        android:name=".EquipmentProfileActivity"
        android:label="Equipment Profile"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove the `supports-screens` element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<supports-screen>` completely or update it like below:

```
    <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: I changed it to this and still no luck. Here's more information:

[Screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/7aa0b3d512f72bdf482d557bb40a2be3.png).